weird aliasing, using one-member anonymous-type union/struct
in example code generated by rpcgen (appname_server.c), there was union used as "define".
  // "define"
  union {
    internal_type internal_name; // special alias
  } arg; // new alias
  
  // arg is accessed by pointer to avoid member access
  // we are using the fact that first member addres
  // is also struct/union address

have you ever seen it or used it in your code ?? i dont see many advantages unless you are a code generator like rpcgen, since it could have been:
  internal_type arg;

from the start.

"it was simmilar to this" - Why wasn't it excatly like this?

Even if you did, it didn't change your question

I believe the Linux kernel uses structure instead of union types like that, with the intent to improve the type safety.  It means you can have variables of different types which all use the same underlying integer type, but you can't pass a variable of the wrong type to a function because the function takes a (pointer to) a specific structure. For example, you could have one type for an engine ID number and another for engine capacity in cc.  If both use a uint32_t type, you could pass the ID where a capacity was expected.  But with two different structure types, you can't make that mistake.

Note that passing such one-element structures or unions is as efficient as passing the element type.  When you need to access the value (to print it, or two compare two of the values), you access the member.  It is a neat and powerful abstraction technique.

This could also be useful if internal_type is an array type, since you can't pass or return arrays by value unless they are inside a struct or union.
